# It is not possible to press the submit button in a form in the datatable

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, datatable

When using a datatable and when a form is placed in one of the row, the submit button cannot be pressed, meaning nothing happens when pressing submit button.
I checked the datatable files and found that the file vendor.js that contains this code:

```
let table1 = document.querySelector('#table1');
let dataTable = new simpleDatatables.DataTable(table1);
```

when remove this code the submit button working well,But the datatable is crashing..
Has anyone faced this problem before or a solution to this problem?
my code:

```html
<table class='table table-striped' id="table1" style="text-align:center; font-size:0.8em;">
             <thead >
              <tr>
                <th style="text-align:center;">#</th>
                <th style="text-align:center;">Product name</th>
                <th  style="text-align:center;">Price</th>
                <th  style="text-align:center;">Edit</th>
                <th  style="text-align:center;">Remove</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="col-sm-5 col-md-5">1</td>
                <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1" style="text-align: center">   Apple  </td>
                <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-center">3$</td>
                <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-center"><form action="Product" method="post"><input class="form-control" step="1" min="1" max="1000" value="<?= $quantity_ordrs; ?>" type="number" name="qty" >
                <input type="hidden" name="order-id" value="1" >
                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary"  name=" update-item"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>edit</button>
                </form></td>
                <td class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 " >
                <form action="Order?kkk" method="post"><input class="form-control" step="1" min="1" max="1000" value="" type="number" name="qty" ><input type="hidden" name="order-id" value="1" >
                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary"  name="remove-item" ><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>remove</button>
                </form>
                </td>
                  </tr></tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something is preventing the default onsubmit event. You can either find the event listener responsible for blocking your submission, or you can create anew listener:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary"  name="update-item"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>edit</button>
```

```
$('[name="update-item"]').on('click', function() {
   $('#myForm').submit();
});
```